# How to make Federated Learning datasets 'tff.simulation.datasets.emnist' from LEAF and NIST?

Tags: tensorflow, federated, nist

I would like to do an image classification task by Federated Learning. According to [tensorflow tutotial], [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification?hl=zh_tw), they download the [original NIST dataset](https://www.nist.gov/srd/nist-special-database-19) and use [LEAF](https://leaf.cmu.edu/) to pre-process them. However, in the tutorial, the details are omitted, they just load 'tff.simulation.datasets.emnist' to get eminist_train and emnist_test. Can anyone know the detail from LEAF's outputs (json files) to the accepted train/test datasets? Thanks

Comment: Any answers? I am trying to make my centralized data in Federated Learning dataset but do not know where to start.